# How to decipher CAN bus message?

Tags: can-bus

I want to to know is it possible to make a script that decipher and document CAN
message. 
My goal is to define which id of CAN bus message is related to speedometer, odometer, Engine RPM etc.

Comment: That question is very broad. Of course you can collect the complete bus traffic. Whether or not you are able to deduce any meaningful information is a different question, since it is up to the manufacturer how the application data is transferred. What is standardized is the OBD-II protocol which will already give you a lot of information about your car.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot know this without knowing the nature of the application layer protocol. CAN is just the lowest levels of the OSI model, it doesn't define anything related to data.

Comment: I saw a video where a guy identified the packet that controls the temperature. He had a testbench setup, when he increased or decreased the temperaure with the dial related to, the second byte of an id started to increase or decrease too, and by that he said that this byte of that id controls the temperature of the car. I wanted to do the same as him but with code and not only identifying the byte of temperature but other components too.

Comment: @Stan So he knew the protocol or had reverse-engineered it. There is no protocol called "CAN", the nature of the data is defined by the application layer. For example something like J1939 or CANopen plus an application-defined spec about what data that corresponds to what package.